# RStudio server ROracle throws : Error in .oci.Driver() : ROracle internal error [rociDrvInit, 1, -1]

Tags: oracle-call-interface, rstudio

I've setup RStudio server and pointed it to use an existing R (2.13) installation. ROracle works fine when accessed from R, but the same does not work from RStudio web-interface.

`> library(ROracle)`

Loading required package: DBI

`> drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")`

Error in .oci.Driver() : ROracle internal error [rociDrvInit, 1, -1]

I installed RStudio server with --nodeps and later pointed it to an existing installation of R
by setting the values in /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf file.

Tried getting help from RStudio support, but was pointed toward "Stack Overflow".
http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/1879-rstudio-roracle-internal-error

Thanks in advance,
Sai.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it working with help from [Denis Mukhin on the Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10215204#10215204). In particular, `ORACLE_HOME` and `OREACLE_SID` were missing in the RStudio environment. Adding the following lines to  `~/.Renviron` fixed it:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1
ORACLE_SID=<your sid (the default is usually orcl)>
export ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID
```

Comment: I've copied in the details from the Oracle forum post, please feel free to edit if I've gotten any of it wrong.